# ロジスティック回帰分析　説明変数が量的な場合の係数

Tags: r

Rでロジスティック分析をする際の質問です。

ロジスティック回帰分析をして、算出された係数は（対数）オッズ比を表していると
理解しています。
説明変数が質的な場合は、2×2のクロス表の形にできるので（対数）オッズ比となることが
わかるのですが、（例　リンク先）
https://istat.co.jp/sk_commentary/risk_odds_04
説明変数が量的な場合はオッズを比較しようにも、どれくらいの幅で、どれくらいの数に説明変数を区切るのか、がわかりません。（区切らない場合はオッズしか算出されないと思うのですが...）
また、3つ以上に説明変数を区切ってしまうと、得られるオッズ比は何と何を比較したものになるのかも不明です。（例えば単位を10で3つに区切ったとすると、0~9のオッズと10~19のオッズを比較するのか10~19と20~29を比較するのか等）
ですが、Rで分析結果はしっかり係数が表示されるので、
1. これがどうやって計算されたものであるか
2. 説明変数が量的な場合、ロジスティック回帰分析をして得られた係数が示すのは、
この説明変数が1単位増加したとき、目的変数が1になる確率（目的変数は二値）がどれだけ増えるか（の値の対数）という理解で合っているのか

の2点をご存知の方がいらっしゃりましたら、ご教授いただきたいです。
また、説明にわかりにくい点がありましたらご指摘ください。

Comment: 簡単でもいいので，再現可能なRのサンプルコードや出力をつけたほうが，より多くの方に回答してもらえると思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

まず，ロジスティック回帰分析は応答変数(被予測変数)が2値(0と1)の場合に用いられる分析で，説明変数が量的でも質的でも用いられます。また，量的な変数は区間で分割することもなく，そのまま投入します。通常の重回帰分析との比較，およびRでの実施方法については，以下のurlを参照してください:

https://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/~okumura/stat/logistic.html
https://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/~okumura/stat/140921.html

質問文にテストコードも出力も付けられていなかったので，説明用に作成します:

```
set.seed(57)

# データ生成
df <- data.frame(
  y = sample(0:1, size = 20, replace = TRUE),
  x1 = round(rnorm(n = 20, mean = 10, sd = 3)),
  x2 = sample(1:2, size = 20, prob = c(2, 3), replace = TRUE)
)

head(df, 1)
#>    y x1 x2
#>  1 0 15  2

# ロジスティック回帰を実施
res_logit <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

# 要約
summary(res_logit)
#>  
#>  Call:
#>  glm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
#>      data = df)
#>  
#>  Deviance Residuals: 
#>       Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
#>  -1.33813  -1.12445  -0.03433   1.21190   1.29199  
#>  
#>  Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
#>  (Intercept)  0.85814    1.84085   0.466    0.641
#>  x1          -0.01641    0.10894  -0.151    0.880
#>  x2          -0.42226    0.95391  -0.443    0.658
#>  
#>  (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#>  
#>      Null deviance: 27.726  on 19  degrees of freedom
#>  Residual deviance: 27.483  on 17  degrees of freedom
#>  AIC: 33.483
#>  
#>  Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

このとき，`Coefficients:`にある部分が係数の出力で，Estimateの部分から，以下のようなモデルが算出されたことを示します:

`logit(pi) = 0.85814 -0.01641*x1 -0.42226*x2`

ここで，`pi`はyが1である確率です。たとえば，あるサンプルs1(今回の先頭行)が`x1 = 15, x2 = 2`であったならば，`y = 1`である確率piはモデルより0.4421220となります。なお，このモデルにより予測された確率は`fitted()`で取り出すことができます:

```
# fitted(モデルにより予測された確率)
fitted(res_logit)
#>          1         2         3         4         5         6         7 
#>  0.4421220 0.5391402 0.4747066 0.4665292 0.4828975 0.4706159 0.5994223 
#>          8         9        10        11        12        13        14 
#>  0.5915158 0.4583698 0.5472846 0.5835616 0.4461737 0.4706159 0.4788006 
#>         15        16        17        18        19        20 
#>  0.5675260 0.5715495 0.4624470 0.4624470 0.4340421 0.4502326
```

また，各説明変数のオッズ比は以下のようにすれば算出できます:

```
# オッズ比に変換
exp(res_logit$coefficients)
#>  (Intercept)          x1          x2 
#>    2.3587740   0.9837221   0.6555637
```

算出しているものについては以上です。また係数の推定値についてですが，量的変数の場合でも質的変数の場合でも，単位量(1)の変化に対応した対数オッズの変化量となります。

Comment: サンプルがある方がわかりやすいとのご指摘ありがとうございました。係数の推定値に関して、説明変数が質的な場合（例えば男と女）は、p＝yが1をとる確率とすると、男のオッズ（p(1)/1-p(1)）と女のオッズ(p(2)/1-p(2))からオッズ比({p(1)/1-p(1)}/{p(2)/1-p(2)})を算出すると理解しています。しかし、量的変数の場合、何と何のオッズ比が算出されているかがRは自動で計算してくれるためわからないのです。もしご説明いただけるならお願い致します。

Comment: 紹介しているリンク先の数式を展開して比較するとイメージがつかめるかと思います。
例えば私の例で，`x1 = 15, x2 = 1`にて算出されたものと`x1 = 14, x2 = 1`にて算出されたlog(logit(pi))を比較した場合，出てくるものはEstimateの値となります。この両辺から対数を除去(指数化)したものと比較してみてください。
質的な二値変数は(0, 1)なので，これと意味するところは同じとなります。